# Cancel removal process of block in layout.xml

Tags: magento2, layout

I want to undo the removal of a block.

the block is removed in `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="true"/>
<referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
<referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
```

[According to the documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_ref), one can canel the removal with `remove=false`.

So I created a file in my theme in `Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false"/>
<referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false"/>
<referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false"/>
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false"/>
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
<referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="false"/>
```

But this does not work. [According to this github issue, it's not a bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1931)

**EDIT:**

[Here's also a related forum post](https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Overriding-block-removal-in-Magento-2/td-p/28662)

Comment: on first sight this sounds like a bug to me. The issue on github got closed I think because it sounds like a question. Maybe if you could provide a complete example in the issue (or maybe also a new issue) to reproduce the behaviour it could be reopened.

Comment: You have to override theme xml file.

Answer (score 4):

No need to override anything, after you add all of these `remove` to `false`

```
<referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false"/>
<referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false"/>
<referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false"/>
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false"/>
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
<referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="false"/>
```

You need to recreate their layout xml again. an example would be to search for `top.search` block and see how it was created and then copy the same block xml in your layout xml file.

An example would be like this

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.description" remove="false" />
```

and right after

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
```

Comment: you are correct! when I asked this question (2 years ago) this was a bug and not working. Meanwhile it's fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same issue and it was solved by overriding the default folder.

By default it is disabled in luma/blank theme. you just need to create basic structure on your theme folder and re-add the blocks you want

yourthemename\Magento_Checkout\layout\override\theme\Magento\blank

just copy checkout_index_index.xml here and in this file paste the below code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
  <!-- <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="true"/>-->
   <!--<referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true"/>-->
    <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
   <!--<referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>-->
</body>
```

You can block remove true/false like this.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like it is a bug, and has now been fixed in Development.

See the discussion on github as issue [#1931](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1931).

The patch itself can be found as: [9bd170d](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/9bd170df9fb459cd3d5fb6fcc76cd1e3ce63919f).

An alternative suggestion, if you have control over parent and child, was to use `display` instead of `remove`

```
<!-- parent_layout_handle.xml -->
+ <referenceContainer name="root" display="false"/>
- <referenceContainer name="root" remove="true"/>

<!-- child_layout_handle.xml -->
+ <referenceContainer name="root" display="true"/>
- <referenceContainer name="root" remove="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and I also want to show header and footer in checkout page so please check this link you will find this useful.

[add header and footer in checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125882/add-header-and-footer-in-checkout-page-magento2/125883#125883)