# Add header and footer in checkout page Magento2

Tags: checkout, layout, magento-2.1

By default Magento 2 don't provide **HEADER** and **FOOTER** in **CHECK OUT** page.

So I checked **checkout_index_index.xml** file on path

```
app/design/frontend/package_name/theme_name/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/base
```

There is **remove** attribute set for header and footer

so I unset remove attribute from **remove=true** to **remove=false**.

But still header and footer is not showing in checkout page so can anyone tell me how can I get header and footer on checkout page?

Comment: "By default Magento 2 don't provide HEADER and FOOTER in CHECK OUT page." <= this is not true. Default Magento 2 provides both footer and header on checkout, your CUSTOM theme deleted them.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism   But I have use magento/blank theme as a parent theme and create my theme.then why checkout page not showing header and footer? I didn't change anything in Magento_Checkout module.I have used default Magento_Checkout module that provided by magento . And this issue is not only for me. I have seen so many developer who has same issue.

Comment: @KetanKp Baroda, have your issue resolved?

Comment: not yet solved...

Comment: @KetanKpBorada Are you want to get only default  header and footer in checkout page, right?

Comment: Yes i want exactly that

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism, actually OP is right. By default Magento doesn't include header and footer, because the checkout layout uses the empty layout handle instead of 1column.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I got a solution.

First go to Magento_Checkout in your theme folder
**app/design/frontend/package_name/theme_name/Magento_Checkout**

Now create below folder structure in layout folder on the above path.
**override/theme/Magento/blank/checkout_index_index.xml**

in this checkout_index_index.xml file add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper" before="-" />
        <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
        <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false" />
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

I hope someone will find this useful.

Comment: *Exception #0 (LogicException): Overriding view file 'D:/xampp/htdocs/nickstore/app/design/frontend/Mytheme/themename/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/theme/Magento/blank/checkout_index_index.xml' does not match to any of the files.* Got this error

Comment: @AsishHira I think you made some mistake to override files.

Comment: No i don't.. I checked it with your answer 12times

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same issue. and i know it is becuase blank theme has no layout/ch‌​eckout_index_index.x‌​ml file.

Comment: XAMPP is not made for running Magento2! You WILL get more errors @AsishHira

Comment: I had to add a `</page>` at the end of this code block to get this to work. Also to answer the other users questions, I placed this file at `app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

Comment: FYI this solution is no good for latter versions of magento. For sure, 2.4+

Answer (score 16):

In Magento 2.1(.1) the logo is moved in the `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` from it's regular place to `checkout.header.wrapper` and then it seems to get lost somewhere..

This is the culpit:

```
<move element="logo" destination="checkout.header.wrapper"/>
```

To get the logo back, add/edit the file:
**[root]/app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  layout="1column"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: 2017 here. Still great!

Comment: Then dont go to 2020 and 2021

Comment: Yep - at least 2.4 magento (not sure which earlier) use a completely different page_layout file. Much more than just the logo will be missing. Notice there is a page_layout folder in vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/. With the new layout for the checkout_index_index page request handle, there is no header-wrapper container, nor is there a header.container . The latter is replaced with checkout.header.container. So whatever in your default pages you had in header.container before, you need to move it to checkout.header.container. Install CommerceBug3 extension, big time saver

Answer (score 7):

For me this worked:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Checkout/page_layout/checkout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
</layout>
```

Comment: We have OSC module installed so this code works for us!

Comment: Yes, I suppose just reverting to the original 1column page_layout seems like the easiest way to correct this. However, if you made any big changes to your header, you'll have to be careful about ordering. Using Alan Storm's CommerceBug3 helps to make this easier to figure out. It creates a nice visual graph of all the containers and blocks as well as the full layout for each page request handle, so you can compare between your normal, looking good page and the checkout page and see what needs to move.

Answer (score 5):

**Magento 2.4**

- Edit checkout index page:
  `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

to be like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper" />
    </body>
</page>
```

- Edit checkout page_layout: `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Checkout/page_layout/checkout.xml`

to be like this:

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content" />
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container" />
        <container name="checkout.header.container" as="checkout_header_container" label="Checkout Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content">
            <container name="checkout.header.wrapper" label="Checkout Page Header" as="checkout_header_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content"/>
        </container>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

***And that's all you need (^_^)!!!***

Comment: Thanks! Worked with M2.4.4

Comment: thanks it worked with Magento 2.4.6 version

Comment: Thanks its work well for me ...

Answer (score 2):

Simple and easy solution for **Magento 2** to display header and footer on checkout page
To display same header and footer on checkout page like other pages, you just override checkout `page_layout` into your theme.

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/page_layout/checkout.xml
```

Copy into your theme

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Your_Theme]/Magento_Checkout/page_layout/checkout.xml
```

Replace `checkout.xml` file code with default `1column.xml` like below and check after removing your cache.

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
<update handle="empty"/>
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
    <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
    <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

I hope it will work for you!

Answer (score 1):

To get the logo back, add/edit the file: `[root]/app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`
        And before end of body tag add this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>
            <move element="header-wrapper" destination="checkout.header.wrapper" before="logo"/> 
            <move element="footer_div" destination="checkout.header.wrapper"/>

        </body>
    </page>
```

Comment: like this<move element="header-wrapper" destination="checkout.header.wrapper" before="logo"/> 
        <move element="footer_div" destination="checkout.header,wrapper"/>

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me and accepted answer results in the following error:

> Exception #0 (LogicException): Overriding view file '/app/design/frontend///Magento_Checkout/layout/override/theme/Magento/blank/checkout_index_index.xml' does not match to any of the files.

Reason for the error there's no `checkout_index_index.xml` file to override in the specified location (under blank theme).

**Solution:**
After consulting devDocs https://goo.gl/gvE23c I had to override the base file for checkout module by copying `checkout_index_index.xml` file from `vendor/module-checkout/layout`directory and copied it over to `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<themename>/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/base`
and changed `layout="checkout"` to `layout="1column"`

Logo was not showing caused by `<move element="logo" destination="checkout.header.wrapper"/>` line so I commented it out and it started to show again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding watsons checkout_index_index.xml to [root]/app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/theme/blank/checkout_index_index.xml

Answer (score 0):

Go to...

[root]/app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

change this line

```
<move element="logo" destination="checkout.header.wrapper"/>
```

to

```
<move element="logo" destination="header-wrapper"/>
```

That worked for me :)

Comment: Great job posting the same answer again ^^ (if that file exists is because some developer in your team/company/you put it there already..)

Answer (score 0):

Now the solution should be

from the adding update handle the page layout 1column to the page layout checkout

- page_layout/checkout.xml

  `<update handle="1column"/>`