# i call this file to enable header on checkout page checkout _index_index.xml like

Tags: magento2

this vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Checkout/layout/o‌​verride/theme/Magent‌​o/blank/checkout_ind‌​ex_index.xml

I am using luma theme

but header does not show on checkout page

Answer (score 1):

If I am right, you want to show your Header part in the checkout page. By default, Magento will not show header. You need to overwrite the checkout_index_index.xml in your theme and use the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>

    <referenceBlock name="header.wrapper" remove="false"/>
    <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="header.panel" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
</body>
</page>
```

Or

This link should help you [Add header and footer in checkout page Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125882/add-header-and-footer-in-checkout-page-magento2)